# Using a ternary statement in Rails 4 in a query using group_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I ran into something interesting that I think would be related to operator precedence, but not sure if I'm just leaving something out. I would like to use a ternary statement in my `.group_by` sort on a DB query in Rails. So I have something like this that works:

```
@tools = Tool.all.group_by {|tool| tool.name}
#=> @tools {'anvil' => [<#tool....
```

which returns a hash tool objects, grouped into keys where the name is the same. It was then brought up that to just sort them into alphabetical groups by first letter of the name would be the desired output so:

```
@tools = Tool.all.group_by {|tool| tool.name.downcase[0] }
#=> @tools {'a' => [<#tool.....
```

So great, now I have a hash of the tools grouped by the first letter of their name. But what if a name starts with a number of something else? Not a problem, it really just pulls the first character and uses that for the group, so tool names starting with "1" get sorted into the hash member whose key is "1". Same for any non-number characters that aren't letters.

Here's the question: I can use a conditional statement to choose to sort all of my alphabetical names into letter groups, but put everything else into a single group with some key like "#". But I can't do it with a ternary statement:

```
@tools = Tool.all.group_by {|tool| if ('a'..'z').include? tool.name.downcase[0] then tool.name.downcase[0] else '#' end }
```

works great! I get all of my non-letter names sorted into the `@tools['#']` part of the hash.

But this does not work:

```
@tools = Tool.all.group_by {|tool| ('a'..'z').include tool.name.downcase[0] ? tool.name.downcase[0] : '#' }
```

It returns a hash with only two members: `@tools[true]` and `@tools[false]`. I can kind of see why, as a ternary operator is returning true or false, but shouldn't it act like the if-then-else statement? It has to be something with the group_by that is jumping the gun?

Is there some way to tweak the syntax of the group_by statement to make the ternary operator work like I want it to? I have tried enclosing the two return statements in parens () but that didn't seem to work. I tried the entire ternary statement in parens hoping it would eval the whole thing before returning to the group_by function... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is being parsed by ruby as

```
 ('a'..'z').include?(tool.name.downcase[0] ? tool.name.downcase[0] : tool.name = '#')
```

which is the same as `('a'..'z').include?(tool.name.downcase[0])`, assuming none of the names are empty?. For it to be equivalent to your previous version you'd need

```
('a'..'z').include?(tool.name.downcase[0]) ? tool.name.downcase[0] : tool.name = '#'
```

As an aside, actually changing the name with `tool.name='#'` sounds like a really bad idea to me. It might not matter here but could easily bite you later on.

Comment: That's actually something I realized, I just wanted to group_by so I changed the return value to just '#'. Will edit.

Comment: Spot on. It was the one way I didn't try the parens. Guess that's one place the method call without () can bite you. It was assuming I was wanting the entire statement in the `include?` method. I knew it had to be something simple like that.  I'll accept as soon as SO lets me. It just said I have to wait two minutes.